# Delegates with multiple methods

Tags: c#, delegates

i have the following example here that should filter a list of string-items

```
List<string> input = new List<string>() { "cat", "toast", "house" };
Func<string, bool> filter = null;
filter += x => x.EndsWith("t");
filter += y => y.Contains('o');
List<string> output = input.Where(filter).ToList(); //toast, house
```

I expect the result to be "toast" because it ends with t and contains o. But the result is toast, house - what is my mistake?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return value of the multicast delegate is the returns value of the last method in the invocation list. So your func only checks if the given parameter Contains `o` and ignores the result of `EndsWith`.

This is stated in `C# 5.0 Specification, §15.4 Delegate Invocations`

> Invocation of a delegate instance whose invocation list contains multiple entries proceeds by invoking each of the methods in the invocation list, synchronously, in order. Each method so called is passed the same set of arguments as was given to the delegate instance.[...] **If the delegate invocation includes output parameters or a return value, their final value will come from the invocation of the last delegate in the list.**

If you wanna check for both conditions use `&&`:

```
filter = x => x.EndsWith("t") && x.Contains('o');
```

Comment: so in my case the first method is being called but ignored? yea, i know that "&&"-solution but i wanted to sove this with multiple methods/lambda-expressions

Comment: @fubo yes. both method is called for each value but only the result of second one is returned which is Contains.

Answer (score 0):

The filter Func return the last method executed use this

```
        List<string> input = new List<string>() { "cat", "toast", "house" };
        Func<string, bool> filter = null;
        filter += x => x.EndsWith("t") && x.Contains('o');
```